# Interval, intermission and break

Tags: word-choice, differences

What are the differences between these 3 words: *interval, intermission* and *break*? I've searched on Oxford Dictionary:

> **interval:**
>
> 1. a period of time between two events
> 2. (also intermission North American English, British English) a short period of time
>
> **intermission**
>
> 1. a short period of time between the parts of a play, film/movie, etc.
> 2. a period of time during which something stops before continuing again
>
> **break**
>
> a short period of time when you stop what you are doing and rest, eat,
> etc.

After reading these definitions, I'm still very confused about when to use *interval, intermission* and *break.*

I have 5 sentences and I have to fill **interval**, **intermission** or **break** correctly:

1. _____ for coffee
2. _____ in conversation
3. _____ for lunch
4. _____ between two acts of play

Comment: All three words  work with #4, with 'break' 
 being a less formal word. On the other hand,  only  'break'  works with the other three, as far as normal usage goes.

Answer (score 1):

You have provided only four of your five examples, and as they are not sentences I understand why you might be having difficulty differentiating between the meanings. Perhaps if I use the examples you've provided in sentences, it might help.

I would use **break** for the first three of your examples.

> *Let's* **break** *for coffee*.

(Let's pause to have a cup of coffee.)

> *There was a* **break** *in the conversation*.

(There was a pause or lull in the conversation.)

> *It is time to* **break** *for lunch*.

(It's time to stop and have lunch.)

> *The time between two acts of a play is called an* **interval** *or an* **intermission**.